# Hooking into fragment's lifecycle like Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

In Android, if you have the Application context you can register an `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` instance that will be called everytime an Activity goes through one of its lifecycle callbacks.

How can I accomplish the same for fragments? I think there is no such interface for Fragments nor any clear place where I would add that.

Maybe customizing a `FragmentHostCallback` creating a `FragmentController` but how can I plug that for the whole application?

The use case is a library that needs to be notified everytime a Fragment calls its lifecycle callbacks and I don't want to create a BaseFragment. I want to be called only from Application's onCreate and that's it (if possible...).

EDIT:

I've created [an issue in Android Open Source Project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232221) about this.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/trello/navi?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since version [25.2.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-2-0) of Android support library, the class `FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` is static and accessible to all.

We can now use an instance of that class and register it in the `supportFragmentManager` of the `Activity`.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {

           // initialization code
          getSupportFragmentManager()
            .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onFragmentPreAttached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Context context) {
                    super.onFragmentPreAttached(fm, f, context);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentAttached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Context context) {
                    super.onFragmentAttached(fm, f, context);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onFragmentCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentActivityCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onFragmentActivityCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentViewCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onFragmentViewCreated(fm, f, v, savedInstanceState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentStarted(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentStarted(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentResumed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentPaused(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentPaused(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentStopped(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentStopped(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentSaveInstanceState(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle outState) {
                    super.onFragmentSaveInstanceState(fm, f, outState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentViewDestroyed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentViewDestroyed(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentDestroyed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentDestroyed(fm, f);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFragmentDetached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                    super.onFragmentDetached(fm, f);
                }
            }, true);
       }
}
```

Comment: Any solution on pre-25.2.0 version?

Comment: Not that I am aware. You could simulate it with a `BaseFragment` approach which is very limited compared to this. i've seen others with more "mystical" ways like having a thread listening for events but have'nt tested it and wouldn't recommend it. Now it is just a matter of updating the support library

Answer (score 4):

Well the activity dispatches its callbacks for the FragmentManager. Later the fragment manager dispatch the calls to the Fragment. There is no place to register the FragmentLifeCycleCallback in the FragmentManager. However at anytime after the fragment is initialized u can get the Fragment state from mState variable in the Fragment.
you can only track the backstack in the fragment manager as below :

```
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Log.i("BACKSTACK","Count" +fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
    });
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class like this, Singleton would be preferred

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class PerfLifecycleCallbacks extends FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks
implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
```

You will have to override lifecycle methods of Fragments, then you can initialize this class anywhere as you may please. Hope this helps