# Tracking Fragment Lifecycle like Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Everyone knows that in Android we can track Activities via Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to obtain fires from system, when Activity created, stopped, destroyed, etc.

I found only one question on stackoverflow related to this theme.
 [Hooking into fragment's lifecycle like Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723055/hooking-into-fragments-lifecycle-like-application-activitylifecyclecallbacks)

Unfortunately provided solution works only on **post** 25.2.0 Android. 
I'm looking for soultion for **pre** 25.2.0. Maybe it could possible via some workarounds, reflection maybe?

Comment: You can track changes in support library [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). Any particular reason not to update?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking for soultion for pre 25.2.0

[`FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html) was available from `25.1.0`. The only change, that was introduced in `25.2.0` concerning this API is, that it [became `static`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-2-0), and before that it was just a public inner class. Which means in order to use you have to access it via its enclosing instance, which in this case is `FragmentManager`:

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(fragmentManager.new FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentPreAttached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Context context) {
                super.onFragmentPreAttached(fm, f, context);
            }
            ...
            // all other callbacks
        }, true);
```

As mentioned in [Eugen Pechanec's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334802/tracking-fragment-lifecycle-like-application-activitylifecyclecallbacks#comment73742807_43337727), default framework fragments (i.e. `android.app.Fragment`, not from support packages) [will receive these changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html) in `Android-O` release.

Comment: Quick note for completeness, the same feature for *platform* fragments [will be available in Android O](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html).