# Which callback should be used to detect android fragment removed from screen and it is not visible anymore

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, onbackpressed, fragment-lifecycle

I use a `FragmentTransaction` to show my fragment inside my activity and also I add it to backstack like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
        .replace(R.id.parentRelativeLayout, myFragment)
        .commit();
```

When back button is pressed I check if `myFragment` is on top and if it is the case, I just call `super.onBackPressed()` to pop it from back stack and show previous fragment.

I want to know which event/callback on my fragment could help me to detect it is not shown on activity anymore.

I used `onPause()`, `onDetach()` and ... but they are not triggered (as it is dsecribed https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252923/1080355)

Comment: [check fragment lifecycle callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723055/hooking-into-fragments-lifecycle-like-application-activitylifecyclecallbacks)

Comment: @sanemars It is not possible to check this inside fragment instance? I noticed that `onFragmentDetached` is called inside activity callbacks but it is not called inside fragment itself.